# How can I configure a custom UserNameMapper using WLST in Weblogic?

Tags: java, weblogic, wlst

You can configure it using the console: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/security/ConfigureCustomUserNameMappers.html

How do you do the same thing in the Weblogic Scripting tool?

I already have example code for a Custom Username mapper, I need to figure out how to tell weblogic about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

```
cd('/SecurityConfiguration/<yourDomain>/DefaultRealm/<yourSecurityRealm>/AuthenticationProviders/DefaultIdentityAsserter')
set('UseDefaultUserNameMapper','false')
set('UserNameMapperClassName','custom.UserNameMapper')
```

Could not find it before because I was doing `dir()` instead of `ls()` .